# Replace values great than a specific value within a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to figure out a way to loop through my data frame and replace any values greater than 200 with a decimal point.

Here is my code:

```
for (i in data$AGE) if (i > 199) i <- i*.01-2
```

Here is a head() sample of my data frame:

```
  AGE LOC RACE SEX WORKREL PROD1 ICD10 INJ_ST DTH_YEAR DTH_MONTH DTH_DAY ACC_YEAR ACC_MONTH ACC_DAY
1  26   5    1   1       0  1290  V865     UT     2003         1       1     2002        12      31
2  20   1    7   2       0  1899   X47     HI     2003         1       1     2003         1       1
3 202   1    2   2       0  1598   W75     FL     2003         1       1     2003         1       1
4  86   5    1   2       0  1807   W18     FL     2003         1       1     2002        12      14
5 203   1    2   1       0  1598   W75     GA     2003         1       1     2003         1       1
6  79   0    1   2       2   921   X49     MA     2003         1       1       NA        NA      NA
```

So basically, if the value of AGE is greater than 200, then I want to multiply that value by .01 and then subtract 2.

**My reason is because any value with 200 and greater is the age in months.**

I'm not a Stats or R genius so my humble thanks in advance for all advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data$AGE[data$AGE> 200] <- data$AGE[data$AGE > 200] * 0.01 - 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this reasonably eleganty `within` and `replace`

```
data <- within(data, AGE <- replace(AGE, AGE > 200, AGE[AGE>200] * 0.01-2))
```

Or using `data.table` for memory efficiency and syntax elegance

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(data)
# make sure that AGE is numeric not integer
DT[,AGE:= as.numeric(AGE)]

DT[AGE>200, AGE := AGE *0.01 -2]
```